# Fetching out lowest and highest date from a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a pandas column like this :

```
 yrmnt
--------
2015 03
2015 03
2013 08
2015 08
2014 09
2015 10
2016 02
2015 11
2015 11
2015 11
2017 02
```

How to fetch lowest year month combination :`2013 08` and highest : `2017 02`

And find the difference in months between these two, ie `40`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connvert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then find indices by `max` and `min` values by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and 
[`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
a = pd.to_datetime(df['yrmnt'], format='%Y %m')
print (a)
0    2015-03-01
1    2015-03-01
2    2013-08-01
3    2015-08-01
4    2014-09-01
5    2015-10-01
6    2016-02-01
7    2015-11-01
8    2015-11-01
9    2015-11-01
10   2017-02-01
Name: yrmnt, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (df.loc[a.idxmax(), 'yrmnt'])
2017 02
print (df.loc[a.idxmin(), 'yrmnt'])
2013 08
```

Difference in `month`s:

```
b = a.dt.to_period('M')
d = b.max() - b.min()
print (d)
42
```

---

Another solution working only with month period created by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
b = pd.to_datetime(df['yrmnt'], format='%Y %m').dt.to_period('M')
print (b)
0    2015-03
1    2015-03
2    2013-08
3    2015-08
4    2014-09
5    2015-10
6    2016-02
7    2015-11
8    2015-11
9    2015-11
10   2017-02
Name: yrmnt, dtype: object
```

Then convert to custom format by [`Period.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Period.strftime.html) minimal and maximal values:

```
min_d = b.min().strftime('%Y %m')
print (min_d)
2013 08

max_d = b.max().strftime('%Y %m')
print (max_d)
2017 02
```

And subtract for difference:

```
d = b.max() - b.min()
print (d)
42
```

Comment: how to find difference?

Comment: @qwww - give me a time

Comment: how can i get the result if i need to add x months with min date...say min date is `2012 09` and i need to add `24` so result should be `2014 09`

Comment: You need working with periods, so use `b.min() + 24`

Comment: i tired it is showing `Period('2015-08', 'M')`..How to get only date without hiphen like `2015 08`

Comment: Then use `(b.min() + 24).to_timestamp()`, check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-between-representations)

Comment: `df.loc[a.idxmin(), 'yrmnt']` in the answer is giving me a dataframe like `0    2012 09
0    2010 10
0    2012 05
0    2009 11
Name: yrmnt, dtype: object` while, `df.loc[a.idxmax(), 'yrmnt']` gives me output like : `2014 09`.. what is the issue?

Comment: Maybe problem index has duplicates, wht return `print (df.index.has_duplicates)` ? [`has_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.has_duplicates.html) ?

Comment: its giving me TRUE

Comment: so first step is necessary `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` for default index.

Comment: Actually I am combining many dfs before applying idxmax or min

Comment: Or use second solution, it working nice with duplicated index too.

Comment: `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` this worked...thanks a lot